# How to make `Menu` in material-ui don't reset scroll position after rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Menu onChange={this.props.onChange}>
  { items }
</Menu>
```

I have a Menu with a lot of items like this, every time when I update the state, the scroll position of the menu is resetted.
I tested with ul

```
<ul>
  { item }
</ul>
```

it works, the position isn't resetted after rerendering.

here is the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/8369729b7f8cd42b06e61cdf201f8ed9c5c7a6b6/src/Menu/Menu.js) of `material-ui/Menu.js`, as I'm new to js, I can't find anything about why the scroll position is resetted.

here is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nw83j4mwrl), if you scroll to the bottom, and then click the `23` item, the scroll position will be resetted.

Comment: What is your code, are you able to link?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin https://codesandbox.io/embed/nw83j4mwrl

Comment: Has my proposed solution helped?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin thank you for your solution, but this is not work, as I add `this.setState({})` after `console.log("Hello");` the scroll position is still been resetted after clicking on an item.

Comment: Link me to the updated code.

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin the same link as before. https://codesandbox.io/embed/nw83j4mwrl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167977/discussion-between-jie-wang-and-paul-mcloughlin).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the event handler, you need to add `preventDefault()` this stops the default action.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MuiThemeProvider, Menu, MenuItem, MenuList } from "material-ui";

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello");
  }

  render() {
    const array = Array.from({ length: 25 }, i => 1);
    const items = Object.keys(array).map(key => {
      return <MenuItem key={key} value={key} primaryText={key} />;
    });
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Menu
          onChange={this.handleChange}

        >
          {items}
        </Menu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I use List instead of Menu to solve this problem.